# Xamarin.iOS ZXing.Net.Mobile barcode scanner

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, zxing, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to add barcode scanner feature to my xamarin.ios app. I'm developing from visual studio and I've added the Zxing.Net.Mobile component from xamarin components store.

I've implemented it as shown in the samples:

```
ScanButton.TouchUpInside += async (sender, e) => {
            //var options = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions();
            //options.AutoRotate = false;
            //options.PossibleFormats = new List<ZXing.BarcodeFormat>() {
            //    ZXing.BarcodeFormat.EAN_8, ZXing.BarcodeFormat.EAN_13
            //};

            var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner(this);
            //scanner.TopText = "Hold camera up to barcode to scan";
            //scanner.BottomText = "Barcode will automatically scan";
            //scanner.UseCustomOverlay = false;
            scanner.FlashButtonText = "Flash";
            scanner.CancelButtonText = "Cancel";
            scanner.Torch(true);
            scanner.AutoFocus();

            var result = await scanner.Scan(true);
            HandleScanResult(result);
        };

void HandleScanResult(ZXing.Result result)
    {
        if (result != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(result.Text))
            TextField.Text = result.Text;
    }
```

The problem is that when I tap the scan button, the capture view is shown  correctly but if I try to capture a barcode nothing happens and it seems the scanner doesn't recognize any barcode.

Someone has experienced this issue? How can I made it work?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: did you try here? https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/zxing.net.mobile  there is a sample code  (I have never had experience with barcode scanner)

Comment: Yes, I followed that sample code but it doesn't work. I've also tryed to run the ios sample from the github repo and it doesn't work too. It may be a problem of my ipad 2 (I'm using this to test)?

Comment: could you follow this ? https://blog.xamarin.com/barcode-scanning-made-easy-with-zxing-net-for-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Unfortunately it's relative to xamarin forms. I need che ios version istead :(

Answer (score 6):

I answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42678187/4286379). I couldn't get barcodes to scan because the default camera resolution was set too low. The specific implementation for this case would be:

```
ScanButton.TouchUpInside += async (sender, e) => {
        var options = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions {
            CameraResolutionSelector = HandleCameraResolutionSelectorDelegate
        };

        var scanner = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanner(this);
        .
        .
        .
        scanner.AutoFocus();

        //call scan with options created above
        var result = await scanner.Scan(options, true);
        HandleScanResult(result);
    };
```

And then the definition for `HandleCameraResolutionSelectorDelegate`:

```
CameraResolution HandleCameraResolutionSelectorDelegate(List<CameraResolution> availableResolutions)
{
    //Don't know if this will ever be null or empty
    if (availableResolutions == null || availableResolutions.Count < 1)
        return new CameraResolution () { Width = 800, Height = 600 };

    //Debugging revealed that the last element in the list
    //expresses the highest resolution. This could probably be more thorough.
    return availableResolutions [availableResolutions.Count - 1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you @bonetoad.  This is the only workaround that is working for ZXing 3.10, Xamarin forms 5.0, and iOS 11+.

Comment: Thank you, it saved me also ! 09/21, lib is still 3.1 beta, project abandoned ?

Comment: I'm not sure. It looks like there was at least some activity on the github repo as recently as 01/19/21: https://github.com/Redth/ZXing.Net.Mobile/releases/tag/3.1.0-beta2

Comment: return availableResolutions [availableResolutions.Count - 1]; - This line didn't return the highest resolution for me.  CameraResolution availableRes = availableResolutions.Where(y => y.Height == availableResolutions.Max(x => x.Height)).FirstOrDefault();
            return availableRes; - This worked for me.